# XSLT: Remove empty elements from a certain depth

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create an xslt that will 'cleanse' the output of many different processes.  I want to remove all empty elements, but some should always be present.

So for example the following

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <typ:GetSomeStuffReturn>
      <typ:abcd>qwer</typ:abcd>
      <typ:efgh/>
      <typ:ijkl>asdf</typ:ijkl>
    </typ:GetSomeStuffReturn>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Should become

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <typ:GetSomeStuffReturn>
      <typ:abcd>qwer</typ:abcd>
      <typ:ijkl>asdf</typ:ijkl>
    </typ:GetSomeStuffReturn>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Easy enough, plenty of examples how to achieve this.

However, this example

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <typ:GetSomeStuffReturn>
      <typ:abcd/>
      <typ:efgh/>
      <typ:ijkl/>
    </typ:GetSomeStuffReturn>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Should become

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <typ:GetSomeStuffReturn/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I cannot work out how to do this.  Everything I have tried works with one or the other example, but never both.

It is further complicated in that the code also needs to work irrespective of what the third node is, it will most likely always end in 'Return'

I always need the Envelope, the Body, and the third node so

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <typ2:LookupThingsReturn>
      <typ2:wxyz/>
      <typ2:stuv/>
    </typ2:LookupThingsReturn>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Should become

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <typ2:LookupThingsReturn/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help or advice gratefully received.

Comment: Show the work you have already done

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself when you say "I want to remove all empty elements, but some should always be present".  I think you mean you want to copy all elements from the input tree except those that are empty, and you acknowledge that doing so may produce empty nodes in the output tree.

Comment: It is furthermore unclear whether you are attributing special significance to the third-level input elements -- for example, must those elements always be copied to the result tree, even if they are empty in the input tree?  Or is it only the children of those elements that must be stripped if empty?

Comment: The work I have already done is essentially copying the many examples on here for related questions and trying to tweak them, all with no success.

Comment: The third element needs to be returned as that identifies the operation that the return is for - and more importantly because the design document and the xsd contract specifies that it should always be there.  But a better way of putting it would probably be that it is only the children of those elements that must be stripped if empty.

Comment: And the grandchildren, etc. of the third-level elements are copied if empty, or not?

Comment: Not.  If there are no values anywhere then the first three elements need to go back.  Any data at any greater depth needs to go back as is.

Comment: @ChrisE You're not being clear about the descendants of the third-level elements.

Comment: This is why I've never asked a question before, trying to explain is harder and more frustrating than writing the code.  I need any elements with values to be returned with those values.  I need no elements without values to be returned.  The only exception to that is when there are zero elements with values in which case I still need the first three elements to be returned.  I apologise for my shoddy efforts at explaining.

Comment: I hate to sound high-handed, but if you cannot explain the problem clearly then that's probably reflective of why you are having trouble solving it.  You are welcome to explain with code or pseudocode if that's easier for you.  In fact, we'd prefer that you do, albeit not exclusively so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node()) and count(ancestor::*) > 2]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Note what happens if you change the `>` to `=`.